# Can't send request during build time in next.js with docker?

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, next.js

I'm trying to send a request in my `getStaticProps` function to my backend api from another docker container. However, even though the api url is written correctly, the static page still is not created. This is because for the static page to be built, the backend should be up already, and because it is build-time the other container is not up yet and waits for the build to be finished and the build can not be finished without the backend.

So what's the solution to this approach? I tried setting the `depends_on` value to my other container, still doesn't work. what solution would you suggest?

Comment: Have You configured network bridge correclty?

Comment: @Davit does this help the connectivity during the docker build? The backend isn't up yet, it's only been built. I have the same situation.

Comment: As far as I know, services are just built in the same order they are defined in the compose file. `depends_on` makes the `docker-compose up` run and stop the services in correct order, and it should be more important, on the other hand, building order shouldn't really matter (at least that is what I think).

Comment: @Davit my `docker-compose.yml` file defines the backend service first. When I run `docker-compose build` the backend service gets built and then next.js image build fails (2nd service on the list) on the `RUN npm run build` command: here the next.js app (frontend) tries to make a call to the backend service (which isn't up yet) during its image build.

Comment: @lexeme please check out the answer and tell me if it works. I really hope I was helpful, cause I hate it when you write all the code but just can't even start it :) Really annoying.

Comment: "@Davit adding network didn't solve the problem. But I'm gonna run a few more tests.

Comment: What about explicitly building and starting back-end service like in the example and building the next.js service? I can't see why that wouldn't work, but please let me know if it does not.

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 solutions I can think of.

Apparently, the Next.js build fails because the service it is querying is not running. Thus why not build and start the service it depends on explicitly and build the rest like this.

```
docker-compose build some_services
docker-compose up -d some_services
docker-compose build the_rest
```

This way the Next.js app will be able to make the request. Please keep in mind that You still need to configure the ports and networks correctly. Pretty sure this will resolve the issue.

A more 'fancy' solution would be using build-time networks which are added in the later versions, `3.4+` if I am not mistaken.

```
docker-compose.yml

build:
    context: ./service_directory
    network: some_network
```

For more details please see [Docker-compose network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network)

Comment: I have been using docker compose for a few years, but I did not know you could selectively start one of the services. This is brilliant. Thank you Davit!!

Answer (score 2):

Running a new service that depends whether another service is up or not is a tricky part of docker orchestration. Keep in mind that even with `Healthcheck`, it doesn't guarantee you database is ready before the next stage. `depends_on` is not going to be really helpful, because it just determine the order of running service. [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on):

> `depends_on` does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web - only until they have been started. What docker doc suggests is to write a [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) script or `[wait-for][2]` and run it after or before depends-on. For example:

```
build: next_service
command: sh -c './wait-for db:5432 -- npm start'
depends_on:
  - db
```

And of course, you explicitly run separate `docker-compose` command but that loses the point of docker orchestration.